# Creating a minesweeper game

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a simplified minesweeper game using a 5x5 2D array. Part of my instruction was to make a function like this:

> This function takes a value between 1 and 25 and converts the value to row column locations. You will need to use reference parameters to accomplish this.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    int input;
    char array[5][5];
    initBoard(array, 5);
    populateBombs(array, 5);
    cout << "Enter a value between 1 and 25 to check a space " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    printBoard(array, 5);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void initBoard(char ar[][5], int size)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            ar[row][col] = 'O';
        }
    }
}

void printBoard(const char ar[][5], int size)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            cout << ar[row][col] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Second part of the question is creating a "populateBomb" function, I need to randomly populates 5 spaces with a bomb. I have to use the '*' character to represent the bomb.Any technique I can utilize to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert an index into column and row using division and modulo [operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

```
// Take an index between 1 and 25 and return 0 based column and rows.
// If you need 1 based column and rows add 1 to column and row
void getPosition(int index, int& column, int& row)
{
    row = (index - 1) / 5;
    column = (index - 1) % 5;
}
```

To select a random column and row use [`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand).

```
void getRandomPosition(int index, int& column, int& row)
{
    getPosition(std::rand() % 25, column, row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> This function takes a value between 1 and 25 and converts the value to row column locations. You will need to use reference parameters to accomplish this.

The function signature should look like:

```
int foo(int in, int& row, int& col);
```

It's not clear from the description whether `row` and `col` need to be between `1` to `5` or between `0` and `4`. Its obvious that the implementation will be different based on what the expected output is.